# g++ not showing correct line number in error output

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, libstdc++

Consider this code

```
#include <map>
#include <memory>

using int_map = std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<int>>;

void f(int_map cl);

void f2() {
    int_map cl;
    f(cl);
}
```

Obviously this code does not compile because `int_map` cannot be copied

But when you compile using gcc:
`g++ -Wall -c example.cpp`
You get this:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/12.1.1/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bits/c++allocator.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/c++/12.1.1/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/12.1.1/bits/stl_tree.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/12.1.1/map:60,
                 from example.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/12.1.1/bits/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::__new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> >; _Args = {const std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> > >&}; _Tp = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> > >]’:
/usr/include/c++/12.1.1/bits/alloc_traits.h:516:17:   required from ‘static void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_Tp1> >::construct(allocator_type&, _Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> >; _Args = {const std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> > >&}; _Tp = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> > >; allocator_type = std::allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> > > >]’
/usr/include/c++/12.1.1/bits/stl_tree.h:595:32:   required from ‘void std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_construct_node(_Link_type, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> > >&}; _Key = int; _Val = std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> >; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> > >; _Compare = std::less<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> > >; _Link_type = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> > >*]’
/usr/include/c++/12.1.1/bits/stl_tree.h:612:21:   required from ‘std::_Rb_tree_node<_Val>* std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_create_node(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> > >&}; _Key = int; _Val = std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> >; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> > >; _Compare = std::less<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> > >; _Link_type = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> > >*]’
/usr/include/c++/12.1.1/bits/stl_tree.h:529:32:   required from ‘std::_Rb_tree_node<_Val>* std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Alloc_node::operator()(_Arg&&) const [with _Arg = const std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> >&; _Key = int; _Val = std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> >; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> > >; _Compare = std::less<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> > >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Link_type = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> > >*]’
/usr/include/c++/12.1.1/bits/stl_tree.h:645:18:   required from ‘std::_Rb_tree_node<_Val>* std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_clone_node(_Link_type, _NodeGen&) [with bool _MoveValue = false; _NodeGen = std::_Rb_tree<int, std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> > >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> > > >::_Alloc_node; _Key = int; _Val = std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> >; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> > >; _Compare = std::less<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> > >; _Link_type = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> > >*]’
/usr/include/c++/12.1.1/bits/stl_tree.h:1895:47:   required from ‘std::_Rb_tree_node<_Val>* std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_copy(_Link_type, _Base_ptr, _NodeGen&) [with bool _MoveValues = false; _NodeGen = std::_Rb_tree<int, std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> > >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> > > >::_Alloc_node; _Key = int; _Val = std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> >; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> > >; _Compare = std::less<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> > >; _Link_type = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> > >*; _Base_ptr = std::_Rb_tree_node_base*]’
/usr/include/c++/12.1.1/bits/stl_tree.h:890:26:   required from ‘std::_Rb_tree_node<_Val>* std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_copy(const std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>&, _NodeGen&) [with bool _MoveValues = false; _NodeGen = std::_Rb_tree<int, std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> > >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> > > >::_Alloc_node; _Key = int; _Val = std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> >; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> > >; _Compare = std::less<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> > >; _Link_type = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> > >*]’
/usr/include/c++/12.1.1/bits/stl_tree.h:901:29:   required from ‘std::_Rb_tree_node<_Val>* std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_copy(const std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>&) [with _Key = int; _Val = std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> >; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> > >; _Compare = std::less<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> > >; _Link_type = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> > >*]’
/usr/include/c++/12.1.1/bits/stl_tree.h:939:23:   required from ‘std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Rb_tree(const std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>&) [with _Key = int; _Val = std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> >; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> > >; _Compare = std::less<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int> > >]’
/usr/include/c++/12.1.1/bits/stl_map.h:217:7:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/12.1.1/bits/new_allocator.h:175:11: error: use of deleted function ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = const int; _T2 = std::unique_ptr<int>]’
  175 |         { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/12.1.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/12.1.1/bits/stl_tree.h:63:
/usr/include/c++/12.1.1/bits/stl_pair.h:195:17: note: ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = const int; _T2 = std::unique_ptr<int>]’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
  195 |       constexpr pair(const pair&) = default;    ///< Copy constructor
      |                 ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/12.1.1/bits/stl_pair.h:195:17: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = int; _Dp = std::default_delete<int>]’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/12.1.1/memory:76,
                 from example.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/12.1.1/bits/unique_ptr.h:514:7: note: declared here
  514 |       unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~
```

You will usually find tons of rubbish.

But **WAIT** in most cases we can filter out what we need using some tools

So try this

`g++ -Wall -c example.cpp 2>&1 |grep example.cpp`

We only care about errors in our code, so we can `grep` useful information by file name

But **SADLY** the command above prints this

```
                 from example.cpp:1:
                 from example.cpp:2:
```

This does not help **AT ALL** since we know clearly there are no error at line 1 and line 2 in `example.cpp`

We need the compiler to tell us where the error is, but it doesn't

It is impossible for a new c++ learner (even a professional c++ programmer) to locate the actual error at **LINE 6** from those long and unreadable error output

---

Trivia:

Clang does not tell you the corrent error location, either. But if you use libc++ (`-stdlib=libc++`), it does. So maybe this is not a gcc problem, but a libstdc++ problem?

Comment: I hear your pain, but I'm not sure what the question is.

Comment: It does not look like to be a complete error message. Seems to be a gcc bug.

Comment: Incidentally Visual Studio reports the problem as originating where you would expect in `main.cpp(10)`.

Comment: @273K The weird thing is that clang print "incomplete" error message, too. I don't think the same bug may appear on different compilers

Comment: Actually, if you wrap your brain around the shown output, the very first line with the "error:" specifies exactly what the error is: a failing copy constructor. And the non-copyable types are given in the error. That's, literally, the error.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The problem is that the type `constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = const int; _T2 = std::unique_ptr<int>]` is too far away from that in my source: `int_map`

Comment: But it tells you: copy constructor, but noncopyable object. Hmm backtrace shows we're in a map. Bingo. And it should never be a big mystery. It's only a Scooby-Doo mystery if one writes a massive pile of code first, and then tries to compile the whole thing. Professional C++ programmers don't write code this way. We only write a few lines at a time, then try to compile, test to make sure they work correctly, then write some more. Yes, C++ errors are often confusing. It takes time to learn how to read them. But, in practice, compilation errors won't have many suspects as their cause.

Comment: fwiw the error is actually at line 10, not line 6 (as @ john said what visual studio reports).